# Unit testing of the updated component in react using jest and enzyme

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, enzyme

I am trying to write the testing file for the following code.
with my present code

```
import React from 'react';
import renderer from 'react-test-renderer';
// import { mount } from 'enzyme';
import LazyToastMessage from '../LazyToastMessage';
import IntlHelper from "test/util/Mount";
import nls from "src/nls/homepageHeader.json";

describe('the suspended toast message component renders correctly', () => {
    const mountWithNLS = new IntlHelper(nls);
    
    it('LazyToastMessage fallback', () => {
        const mockHandler = jest.fn();
        const wrapper = renderer.create(mountWithNLS.mountWithIntl(
        <LazyToastMessage
        state
        message="test message"
        iconType="success"
        handleToasterStateChange={mockHandler}
        />)
        )
        expect(wrapper.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
    })
});
```

The result of the snapshot is giving as `null`. How can I test the updated component and take its snapshot?

The Lazy component is the following:

```
import React, {lazy, Suspense} from "react";
import {IAppProps} from 'src/js/components/misc/ToastMessage'

const LazyToastMessage = lazy(() =>
    import(/* webpackChunkName: "toast-message" */ "./ToastMessage"),
);

export default function(props: IAppProps) {
    return (
        <Suspense fallback={null}>
            <LazyToastMessage {...props} />
        </Suspense>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To test it properly, you have to wrap your lazily loaded component in `Suspense` in test.

First, in your component:

```
export const LazyToastMessage = ...
```

Then, in your test:

```
import SuspendedLazyToastMesssage, {LazyToastMessage} from '../LazyToastMessage';

.
.
.
const wrapper = renderer.create(mountIthNLS(mountWithIntl(
    <Suspense fallback=null>
        <SuspendedLazyToastMessage/>
    </Suspense>
));

await LazyToastMessage;

expect(wrapper.toJSON()).toMatchSnapshot();
```

Or something like that, but you get the idea...